# Sql subquery issue suming subfields

Tags: sql, sum, subquery

I am trying to get a subquery to work but i cant get past subquery returned more than 1 value. this is not permitted. No matter how i try to re-write this query I cannot get this sum area to work. I am only fairly new to subqueries so any assistance you could provide would be great the query currently stands as

```
    SELECT        dbo.h.DateDelivery, dbo.h.DateInProduction, dbo.h.JobNumber, dbo.h.JobKeyID, dbo.h.QuantityFrames, dbo.h.QuantityGlass, dbo.h.QuantityPanels, 
                         dbo.r.Description, dbo.r.DivisionID, dbo.r.rKeyID, (SELECT        SUM(t.QtyPacks) AS packqty
FROM            t INNER JOIN
                         h ON t.JobKeyID = h.JobKeyID
WHERE        (t.StageID = 10) OR
                         (t.StageID = 20) OR
                         (t.StageID = 28)
GROUP BY t.JobKeyID)
FROM            dbo.h INNER JOIN
                         dbo.r ON dbo.h.rKeyID = dbo.r.rKeyID
WHERE        (NOT (dbo.r.rKeyID IN (1, 50, 81, 91)))
```

Comment: Format your code properly.  No one is going to read that.

Comment: Also tag your question with your dbms.

Comment: " but i cant get past subquery returned more than 1 value." Run only your subquery.  Does it return more than 1 value?  If yes, then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which DBMS you are using, however in general a scalar subquery expression must return exactly one column value from **one row** (see for instance the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Scalar-Subquery-Expressions.html#GUID-475D80C3-C873-4475-AB1A-8837C5CF8CE4)).

In your code there is a `GROUP BY t.JobKeyID` which might cause the subquery to return more than one row.

Comment: Thanks I am using ms sql. My subquery returns a result per jobkeyid which is the same as the main query is there a way to link the 2 queries or some other solution?